# Django Rest API login using multiple password

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-login

I have one type of login idea, One single `User` has multiple `Accounts` (OneToOne or Foreign Key). To save `UserEmail` I use the default `User` table.

Account Model

```
class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = EncryptedTextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_name
```

Transaction Model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(),primary_key=True,editable=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='account')
    transaction_no = models.CharField(default=str(uuid.uuid4())[:8],max_length=100)
    transaction_line_items = models.ManyToManyField("TransactionLineItem")
    cgst_per = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    igst_per = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sgst_per = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    main_biiling_account = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='main_biiling_account')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.transaction_no
```

1. `UserID` is PrimaryKey on the `User` table.
2. In the `Account` table, `Account__UserID` is ForeignKey assigned to the `User` table.
3. Now `Account` table `AccountID` PrimaryKey is assigned as ForeignKey for other tables(e.g: `Transaction` table have `Transaction ID, AccountID, TransactionAmount`. In `Transaction` table `AccountID` ForeignKey of `Account` table).
4. When the user login by using the `User` table `UserPassword`. The user gets a list of `Account` table data. `Account` table PrimaryKey `AccountID` as ForeignKey for `Transaction` table, so users now get List `Account` & List `Transaction` data (It's default login method).
5. When the user login by using the `Account` table `AccountPassword`. The user gets only one `Account` data. so now user get only one `Account` & List `Transaction` data (Account-based login)

Now I did the default login method, it's an easy one. My question is, how I can do Account-based login.
[image]

Comment: Could you share a bit of your code you are currently using?

Comment: Can you determine if the entered data is account data or user data? Do the account name all start with the same character?

Comment: Is it true, that the any account_name is never used as a username?

Comment: No account name is just a name to identify the account for the user. If the user login by using a user model password, the user gets all account data related data, but user uses the account-model password, the user gets only that particular account-related data only

Comment: And I update models code

Comment: Is it really neccessary to assign a password to the account? Maybe just use the default users and make n:m relations to accounts. This way you simplify your login. The users in your draft could have multiple accounts assigned, but the former account logins in your draft would be allowed to have only assigned a single account.

Comment: yes it's necessary

Comment: please help buddy, it's basic for this project

Comment: why about creating Verifying user Page before the User Open his accounts , or Make Transactions , he must enter his password ? if you really want this so you can do the same before opening this page he must go throw the login account page

Comment: The project needs 2 different types of login. 1st one is a general user login, after login, I pass the token to Accounts API then I get the list of accounts and list of Transactions (ForeignKey of AccountID). 2nd login is Account-based login. In this method, I want to get single account data and that single account-related list of Transactions